# Find a word in window

Tags: winforms, string, find

How can i find a word in a string that im searching with :

```
myProcess.MainWindowTitle
```

Lets say that i want :

```
if myProcess.MainWindowTitle = something.contains("calc.exe") then
```

or

```
    if myProcess.MainWindowTitle = contains.myproccessNAme then
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Process.MainWindowTitle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowtitle.aspx) is a `string`, so you can simply use [String.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) method:

```
if (myProcess.MainWindowTitle.Contains("calc.exe")) then
```

Comment: that was cute, it restart my pc LOL, im not so sure that works

Comment: ´if myProcess.MainWindowTitle.Contains("calc.exe") then´
thanks alot :)